# How to replace a createText node with another string - Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following is a function to display letters inputted by the user on an html page. I want it to come like this:

[image]

But I end up with something like this:

[image]

How do  make it so that only the **last string** appears?

Here is my code:

```
var words = ['quaffle', 'bludger', 'pensieve', 'harry', 'lupin', 
'butterbeer', 'polyjuice', 'patronus', 'horcrux', 'voldemort'];
correctletters='';
missedletters='';

function getRandomWord(){
   randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length)]; 
   wordlength = randomWord.length;
}

function getGuess(){
    letterGuessed = document.getElementById("inputfield").value.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("inputfield").value = null;
    alert(randomWord);
    alert(letterGuessed);
    r = randomWord.includes(letterGuessed);

    if(r == true){
        correctletters = correctletters + letterGuessed;
        alert("correct letters: "+correctletters);
    }

    else{
        missedletters = missedletters+letterGuessed;
        alert("missed letters: "+missedletters);
    }
    guess = missedletters + correctletters;
    displayGuessedLetters();
}

}

function displayGuessedLetters(){
   guessedletters = document.createElement("div");
   content = document.createTextNode(guess);
   guessedletters.appendChild(content);
   container = document.getElementById("inputcontainer");
   container.appendChild(guessedletters);
   guessedletters.style.cssText = 'font-family: "Josefin Sans"; font-size: 
   30px; text-transform: uppercase; color: rgb(255, 85, 49);';
}
```

**EDIT:** The thing is when a user types a letter. It gets displayed on the webpage without these repetitions. For example, if the user types 'a', the container will show 'a'. Next time the user types, 'b', the container should have 'a b' **only** instead of a, then showing ab.

Comment: you can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) like that: `guessedletters.innerHTML = content`

Comment: try display:inline-block

Comment: @Cinn When I try that nothing comes up.

Comment: @Devika.S By using `guessedletters.appendChild(content)` you add a new child at each `displayGuessedLetters()` call. The purpose of `innerHTML`/`innerText` is to overwrite the content of an element. So try something like ``container.innerHTML(`<div>${guess}</div>`)``. (and put the css somewhere else like `#inputcontainer div { font-family: ...etc }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add all relevant code parts in your next Questions (like `correctLetters`, `missedletters` and so on)

You are adding a new DIV each time the `displayGuessedLetter` function is called. You just need to append the new `letterGuessed` to the content:

```
function displayGuessedLetters(){
   content = document.createTextNode(letterGuessed);
   container = document.getElementById("inputcontainer");
   container.appendChild(content);
}
```

Just add a space in between and apply the CSS styles to the container. I would also rename the "inputcontainer" to "outputcontainer".

If my code does not fit your needs, just comment and i will try have a look!
cheers

**EDIT**:
working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncpfxqhL/6/

Comment: The thing is when a user types a letter. It gets displayed on the webpage without these repetitions. For example, if the user types 'a', the container will show 'a'. Next time the user types, 'b', the container should have 'a b' **only** instead of a, then showing ab. I shall update my post with the rest of the code.

Comment: you should btw try to use less global variables. It may lead to confusing errors when you use the same variable name in a different scope.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks! Its exactly what I needed.